# Web scraping multiple StockCharts urls using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Some days ago I asked about scraping data from StockCharts and I got this code that works very well:

```
Sub StockCharts_By_Subsector()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Navigate "https://stockcharts.com/freecharts/sectorsummary.html?&G=SECTOR_DJUSHP&O=1"

    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'wait for java script to load
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
    With HTMLDoc.body
        Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
            For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                Next lngCol
            Next lngRow
            ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
        Next lngTable
    End With
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

At the url you can see the sector code (DJUSHP) but in fact I need to get data from multiple sectors I have in a long list. For example, next ones:

DJUSHP - DJUSOL - DJUSOI - DJUSPL

How could I have all these data together at the same sheet? I assume I need an Excel VBA Loop but I am not able to built it up.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can see, the code reads the first page of the given sector. If there are more than one page, you need 2 loops if you need all pages of all sectors. The requested loop has to reassemble the URL for you on every pass. I don't have time now, but inform yourself about parameters of URLs (First one after the questionmark [?], all others after each ampersand [&]. The order doesn't matter.)

Comment: Try this [link](https://c.stockcharts.com/j-sum/sum?cmd=perf&group=SECTOR_DJUSHP&r=0.5476387047958533) to parse the json content from there instead of piloting IE.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both for your help. Regarding the Json content of that website I am afraid I am not able to pase it :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant to achieve:

```
Sub StockChartsBySubsector()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object, lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long, lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long, ActRw As Long
    Dim stockList As Variant, stock As Variant
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    
    stockList = Array("DJUSHP", "DJUSOL", "DJUSOI", "DJUSPL")
    
    For Each stock In stockList
        objIE.Visible = False
        objIE.navigate "https://stockcharts.com/freecharts/sectorsummary.html?&G=SECTOR_" & stock & "&O=1"
        Do Until objIE.readyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'wait for java script to load
        
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.document.body.innerHTML
        With HTMLDoc
            Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
                For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                    For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                    Next lngCol
                Next lngRow
                ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
            Next lngTable
        End With
    Next stock
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SIM. Yes, this is the idea. To list all the stocks together. I know you use other code from other times you helped me but I just had this one. I have three questions: 1. As example I wrote 4 sectors but I actually have 110 to scan. Is there a maximum of elements an array can admit? 2. How could I do to list the header just the first time and to avoid empty rows between sectors? 3. I want to list the sector ticker (stock) on column 9. Where should I insert the code?.

Comment: Why do you even think of putting all the tickers in an array!! You should read the tickers from any spreadsheet and use them in the url. As for your last two questions, it is necessary to bring about a massive change in your current attempt to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot SIM. I would appreciate very much if you could help me regarding that